# Anki: How can I mark the cards that I already know in an imported deck?

Tags: anki

I'm trying out Anki for myself and I have imported various deck about non-Latin writings systems, some of which I have at least already partly learnt.

When importing an external card deck, Anki will present me with at most N (according with my config) new characters per day. How can I manually mark the card that I already know from the beginning or cards which I learnt from another source ?

**examples :**

If I only have a small deck, like the Hebraic alphabet or Greek alphabet, I could just temporary raise the number of new cards per day, to set them all as `new` by quickly browsing the whole deck.

However, if I'm studying Kanji or Hanzi from some specific course and I have an imported deck in which I would like to activate those characters I learnt before or just now from the course. Obviously, I only want to manually add those specific characters and I do not wish to wait until I have browsed the whole deck for those characters I already know, to appear by themselves (which might take years if I'm a slow learner).

**There might be two cases :**

1. There are some characters that I know and I just want Anki to know it so that it can put them in the review list, or
2. there are some character that I partially know e.g. I learnt them from somewhere but my deck will provide me with more information than I already got, and I want Anki to present them to me right know (put to put them first in the list of new cards) instead of waiting months or years, that I find them by chance when Anki decides to show them to me.

However, this difference is not really important, because, as @Tommi mentioned : Anki will manage. The only really important point is to have (1) or (2) instead of having them presented much later.

Comment: Thanks for the edit; I have upvoted the question and removed my answer, which is now obsolete.

Comment: I do not wish to change anything in Anki strategies. I just want to inform it about the characters in the list, which I already learnt from another source. It might be interesting to be able to tell it if I've been knowing those characters for long, or if I just learnt them right know (i which case they might be added in today new characters), but that's a secondary consideration.

Comment: I don't know what you don't understand, @user02814. What I wan't is just for anki to know that I know some cards of the deck that it never presented me, so that it includes them in the `cards to be reviewed` list or right now as `new` instead of presenting them as `new`, someday in a far future.